# Spring MVC Data Binding: bind parameter to an object field with different name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
    public void addMember(Member member) {
        // ... ...
    }
```

here is `Member` class:

```
class Member {
    private Integer id;
    private String username; 

    // ... ...
}
```

And here is the request url:

```
/add?memberId=1&username=bruce
```

How can I bind the `memberId` parameter to `Member.id` field?
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot at least not without implementing your own `DataBinder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public void addMember(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username, ...) {
    Member member = new Member(username, ...)
    // ...
}
```

you can implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver:

```java
public class MemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return Member.class.equals(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
       NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        String username = webRequest.getParameter("username");
        ...
        return new Member(username, ...);
    }
}
```

And in config:

```java
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean id="memberResolver" class="com.company ... MemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

or JavaConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 ...
  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<Handlermethodargumentresolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new MemberHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe this is the standard way to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

IMHO the simplest way to do that is to use an additional setter in `Member` class :

```
class Member {
    private Integer id;
    private String username; 

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setMemberId(Integer memberId) {  // this one should to the trick
        this.id = memberId;
    }

    // ... ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution is the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@JsonProperty** Annotation for it.Like below.

```
class Member {
    @JsonProperty("memberId")
    private Integer id;
    private String username; 

    // ... ...
}
```